# pytest: creating a mock object for a function with a different return value depending on the input

Tags: python, pytest

I want to test a function that makes use of the builtins.open function and want to return a value depending on which path was provided. So far my function looks like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_open(self,mocker):
    mock_file = mocker.patch('builtins.open', return_value=StringIO("mock open"))
    return mock_file
```

Is there a way to say "if path==a then return "mock a", else return "mock b"?

Answer (score 2):

Use [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) to intercept the call to `open()` and act accordingly based on the `file` parameter.

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_open(self, mocker):
    def _mock_open(file, *args, **kwargs):
        if file == "a":
            return StringIO("For a")
        return StringIO("For b")
    mock_file = mocker.patch('builtins.open', side_effect=_mock_open)
    return mock_file
```